# Would there be a solution that the left "aside" would stay sticky, while I was scrolling up and down the right div?

Tags: html, css

I have a css question with the example below. Supposedly there will be an `addEventListener` for each `article` in Javascript, for the users to click on them and go to other pages. However, they are omitted in this piece of code now, since they're not relevant to my question. I'd like to ask if there is some mistakes in my code that could be corrected, or would there be any solutions to make the `aside` on the left to be sticky, while I'm scrolling up or down for the div `boxes`on the right?

Thank you!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem;
}

#a {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

article {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 12rem;
  padding: 3%;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

article:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <aside id="a">
      <h1>abcde</h1>
    </aside>
    <div id="boxes">
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>a</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>b</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>c</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>d</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>e</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? A question with the exact same requirements was just asked a couple of days before. The solution stays the same. [Two Columns - One Column Overflows & Other Fixed - Shared Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77460234/two-columns-one-column-overflows-other-fixed-shared-scroll)

Comment: Thanks @tacoshy for your solution. At first I thought they are the same questions and your answer should be the modal answer, but eventually Burham's solution solved it. Changing from flex to grid in ".main" display and adding the grid-template-columns, in css, doesn't work for me unfortunately, but I appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to fix your CSS as long as you're targeting .boxes while it needs to be #boxes, as long as boxes is an ID not a Class

now, you need to use Sticky position at the element to be sticky and set the top to 0, so it will keep sticky at offset Top 0,

i have made this snippet with some more edits, like setting the boxes height, and allow scrolling without moving the sticky part.

check the snippet result,

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem;
}

aside#a {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:3rem;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  margin-right: 4rem;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:100%;
}
/* Vertical */
#boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height:100vh;
  max-width:100vw;
}

article {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 12rem;
  padding: 3%;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

article:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <aside id="a">
      <h1>abcde</h1>
    </aside>
    <div id="boxes">
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>a</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>b</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>c</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>d</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>e</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
       <div>
        <article>
          <h3>f</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
       <div>
        <article>
          <h3>g</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
       <div>
        <article>
          <h3>h</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

---

as long as you're using the flex in row so this time you can check for column direction

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem;
  width:100%;
}

aside#a {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:3rem;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  margin-right: 4rem;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
}
/* Horizontal */
#boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height:100vh;
  width:55%;
}

article {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 12rem;
  padding: 3%;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

article:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <aside id="a">
      <h1>abcde</h1>
    </aside>
    <div id="boxes">
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>a</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>b</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>c</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>d</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div>
        <article>
          <h3>e</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
       <div>
        <article>
          <h3>f</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
       <div>
        <article>
          <h3>g</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
       <div>
        <article>
          <h3>h</h3>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```